# Minimum value of vector displays as 0

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to display both the maximum and minimum value of a vector (along with other things). The max value displays fine, but the minimum value constantly comes up as 0. The only time it's not 0, it ends up displaying the final value of the list of data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("dataWin.txt");

    vector<float> dist;
    while(file.eof() == false)
    {
        string miles;
        getline(file, miles);
        float milesNum = atof(miles.c_str());
        dist.push_back(milesNum);
    }

    float max = 0.0;
    float min = 1.0;
    float sum = 0.0;
    float secHour = 3600;
    float lastRecord = 238857;

    for(int i = 0; i < dist.size(); i++)
    {
        if(dist[i] < min)
            min = dist[i];
        if(dist[i] > max)
            max = dist[i];
        sum += dist[i];
    }

    float avg = (float)sum / dist.size();
    float lastSeconds = (float)lastRecord / (float)avg;
    float deadline = (float)lastSeconds / (float)secHour;   

    cout << "National Aeronautics and Space Administration - NASA" << endl;
    cout << "EYES ONLY" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Statistics on solar object 326 Alba" << endl;
    cout << "Danger level: HIGH" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Maximum travel distance: " << max << " miles per second." << endl;
    cout << "Minimum travel distance: " << min << " miles per second." << endl;
    cout << "Average travel distance: " << avg << " miles per second." << endl << endl;
    cout << "WARNING! OBJECT 326 Alba WILL IMPACT IN " << deadline << " HOURS!" << endl;

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the actual min value of the list to display?

Comment: Why don't you just initialize them to dist[0]?

Comment: What's the expected range of the data in `dataWin.txt`?

Comment: I've tried that, as well, and the minimum value still shows as 0 while max is correct.

Comment: The minimum value should show up as 0.000103198 miles per second.

Comment: Try outputting `milesNum` in your loop (or use a debugger) to make sure all of the values are being read in properly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when input ends the `getline` call will fail and it will not update the string, you are then converting an empty string to a float which is failing in the `atof` call (if `atof` fails, it will return `0.0`) and pushing that value into the vector. The minimum value in the vector is now `0` and the algorithm is correctly yielding it as the minimum.

If you are going to code that in C++, and assuming that the only contents of the input are floats and spaces, you can make the code simpler by reading directly into a float:

```
float miles;
while ( std::cin >> miles ) {
   dist.push_back( miles );
}
```

Even simpler, you can avoid the loop altogether by using iterators and algorithms from the STL:

```
std::vector<float> dist;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<float>( std::cin ), std::istream_iterator<float>(),
           std::back_inserter( dist ) );
std::cout << "Max: " << *std::max_element( dist.begin(), dist.end() ) << "\n";
std::cout << "Min: " << *std::min_element( dist.begin(), dist.end() ) << "\n";
std::cout << "Sum: " << std::accumulate( dist.begin(), dist.end() ) << std::endl;
```

This is just to show what can be done with existing algorithms. In your particular case I would use the `std::copy` and `std::istream_iterator`s for reading the input, but for processing the already read numbers I would unroll a manual loop (so that all min, max and sum can be calculated in one pass, the STL examples above do it in three passes).

Comment: Also, C++0x adds `std::minmax_element` to get both in a single traversal.

Comment: @ildjam: That would still require a second pass to obtain the sum, I would still unroll a loop for in C++0x: `for ( int x : dist ) { min = std::min( min, x ); max = std::max( max, x ); sum += x; }` or with iterators in c++03. The loop is simple takes a single extra line of code, and it is just as readable. From the `minmax_element` algorithm, I tend not to like functions that return `std::pair<>` objects (user code looks awkward) and more so when the returned pair is of iterators: `auto r = std::minmax_element( dist.begin(), dist.end() ); min = *r.first; max = *r.second;`, really?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
while(file.eof() == false)
{
    string miles;
    getline(file, miles);
```

should be:

```
string miles;
while( getline(file, miles) )
{
```

Where are you picking up the idea you need to call eof() from? You don't, and doing so in the way you are doing it is wrong!

Comment: It shouldn't affect the way the program operates though. I'm just putting a loop to input every value into the vector until we reach the end of the file.

Comment: @joker Yes, it does affect the way the program operates, as the two bits of code do completely different things! Consider what happens if you use your code on an empty file.